# Is there a better way than this to implement Softmax Action Selection for Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, random, reinforcement-learning, softmax

I am implementing Softmax Action Selection policy for a reinforcement learning task (http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node17.html).

I came with this solution, but I think there is room for improvement.

1-Here I evaluate the probabilities

```
    prob_t = [0]*3
    denominator = 0
    for a in range(nActions):
        denominator += exp(Q[state][a] / temperature) 

    for a in range(nActions):
        prob_t[a] = (exp(Q[state][a]/temperature))/denominator
```

2-Here I am comparing a random generated number in the range ]0,1[ to the probabilities value of the actions:

```
    rand_action = random.random()
    if rand_action < prob_t[0]:
        action = 0      
    elif rand_action >= prob_t[0] and rand_action < prob_t[1]+prob_t[0]:
        action = 1      
    else: #if rand_action >= prob_t[1]+prob_t[0]
        action = 2
```

edit:

example: rand_action is 0.78, prob_t[0] is 0.25, prob_t[1] is 0.35, prob_t[2] is 0.4.
the probabilities sum to 1. 
0.78 is greater than the sum of the probabilities for action 0 and 1 (prob_t[0] + prob_t[1]) therefore action 2 is picked.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is `nActions` the size of `Q[state]` ? Do you have `numpy` ?

Comment: Yes, nActions is the number of the possible actions and therefore the size of every Q[state]. and I do have numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestions to use numpy I did a bit of research and came with this solution for the first part of the soft-max implementation.

```
prob_t = [0,0,0]       #initialise
for a in range(nActions):
    prob_t[a] = np.exp(Q[state][a]/temperature)  #calculate numerators

#numpy matrix element-wise division for denominator (sum of numerators)
prob_t = np.true_divide(prob_t,sum(prob_t))
```

There's a for loop less than my initial solution.
The only downside I can appreciate is a reduced precision.

using numpy:

```
[ 0.02645082  0.02645082  0.94709836]
```

initial two-loops solution:

```
[0.02645082063629476, 0.02645082063629476, 0.9470983587274104]
```

Comment: what is the temperature value being used, is it a hyper parameter? How do decide it? Thanks

Comment: @cvg the Temperature is used to regulate how differences in values translate to probabilities: (as per the link in the original question http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node17.html).

It is not necessarily a hyper parameter to be tuned, I guess it depends on your application.

Answer (score 2):

Action selection based on probabilities can be easily done using numpy library.

```
q_values = [] #array of q_values
action = np.random.choice(q_values,p=q_values)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you evaluate the probabilities for each action, if you have a function to return you weighted random selection, you can get your desired action like this:

```
action = weighted_choice(prob_t)
```

Though I am not sure whether this is what you call "better way".

The `weighted_choice` can be something like [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/):

```
import random
def weighted_choice(weights):
    totals = []
    running_total = 0

    for w in weights:
        running_total += w
        totals.append(running_total)

    rnd = random.random() * running_total
    for i, total in enumerate(totals):
        if rnd < total:
            return i
```

Definitely check the binary search implementation in the article instead of the linear search one above if you have a lot of available actions.

Or if you have access to [numpy](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/#comment-253694):

```
import numpy as np
def weighted_choice(weights):
    totals = np.cumsum(weights)
    norm = totals[-1]
    throw = np.random.rand()*norm
    return np.searchsorted(totals, throw)
```

Comment: prob_t is a list that contains the probabilities for each possible action, its values sum up to 1. 
By doing the first for in your function running_total will be 1.
Why do you suggest doing this?

Comment: Instead of doing if..elif..else for 3 possible actions, is this a more efficient way to picking up your desired action? I might be wrong, because I don't know how to define "better" in your original post.

Comment: editing the question now to explain better how I choose the action.
better as in more efficient, less computation (comparisons, loops)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list with your action ids:

```
actions = [0, 1, 2]
```

You can use numpy random choise with a probability list:

```
action_int = numpy.random.choice(actions, p=prob_t)
```

You can prove this by iterating over this statement a few times:

```
results = []
for i in range(30):
    actions = [0, 1, 2]
    prob_t = [0.6, 0.1, 0.3]

    action_int = np.random.choice(actions, p=prob_t)

    results.append(action_int)

print(results)
```

And you will get something like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```